# java exec or runtime not working useing ssh

Tags: java, linux, ssh, exec

I have 2 servers A and B. I run a ssh command from server A to server B

```
ssh userB@B "java -jar runCommand.jar"
```

In runCommand.jar there is a exec command:

```
String cmd = "/home/user/runThisShell.sh";
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

The runThisShell.sh creates .txt file and prints to it "ABC"

The problem is that when I connect to server B and run runThisShell.sh it work and create the file but when I run it from server A it doesn't work.

The ssh command not run all the jar on the B server?

Comment: Are you logging into A&B as the same user? Do both servers have the required files? Is Java even installed on both?

Comment: no i connect with diffrent users to the servers.all the files is on server B and java is install on the boat of the servers

Comment: So you're using 'user' on B, but perhaps 'SO' on A ? Then your problem probably lies in the fact that the jar is trying to find something in the homedirectory of user, while the only it should be able to find on A is the home directory of 'SO' (in my example)

Comment: I use userB on server B and userA on server A